# What parts of Zack Snyder's Justice League were retained from the original?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017, zack-snyders-justice-league

Recently, another version of *Justice League* was released. This version, dubbed *Zack Snyder's Justice League*, has been characterized as a director's cut of the original, suggesting that most of the major plot points are the same, but it also has been described as a soft remake of the film. On a first watchthrough, many things are clearly different: the introduction, for instance, or the expanded role played by Darkseid. Indeed, as indicated in the comments, a good three-quarters of the film consists of entirely new material.

Given that there have been such drastic changes, how much of the plot has been kept? Which elements have been retained from the original?

Comment: @Valorum - Care to provide an answer in addition to a vote? You might think the question is not of interest to anyone, but a hundred-odd (usually quite incomplete) news articles about the differences between the two seem to disagree.

Comment: Hmm, isn't it kinda "list question" - rather too broad?

Comment: @Mithoron I suspect it can be summarized in a relatively brief answer.

Comment: And then comes half a dozen others... I think I'll refrain from flagging, but wouldn't be surprised if the post gets closed.

Comment: The answers are endless, but here is a summary that can help: https://screenrant.com/justice-league-zack-snyder-cut-2017-changes-explained/

Comment: https://screenrant.com/justice-league-movie-zack-snyder-cut-footage-how-much/ - 3/4 of the new 'cut' is footage that wasn't seen in cinemas.

Comment: @Valorum - In that case, the question should be turned around: what has remained the same between the two?

Comment: They managed to keep the part where it isn't very good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Which elements have been retained from the original?

Limiting the question to Visual Effects, in an interview with BuzzPopTV, Director Zack Snyder and Producer Deborah Snyder, state that only 11 out of 2656 visual effects shots were carried over from the 2017 theatrical release.

Here at 15m38s

Weta Digital Visual Effects Supervisor Anders Langlands and Animation Supervisor Simeon Duncombe corroborate the figure in an interview with The Reel Roundup.